# Specify the gender using enum

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

When using an enum, I have to specify the gender. In my country, **women's names end with 'a'**.
What I did:

```
public enum Gender {
    MEN, FEMALE
}
```

I wish the program would take a name and be able to determine gender based on that, but I have no idea what the next steps should be.

Comment: `Gender gender = name.endsWith("a") ? Gender.FEMALE : Gender.MALE`?

Answer (score 1):

Enums can have static methods, which is perfect for a situation like this.

```
enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;

    public static Gender getGender(String name) {
        if (name.endsWith("a")) return FEMALE;
        return MALE;
    }
}
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_endswith.asp) for more info on endsWith()

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I think to begin it's important to really understand what an Enum is, it's effectively a special class that has some constant unchangeable variables, in this case you have MEN and FEMALE which will not change.

You can access the variables within your Enum using dot syntax,
for example:

```
Gender Paula = Gender.FEMALE;
```

This would set a new instance of your Gender Enum called Paula and set it's gender value to FEMALE.

When then accessing that variable you have made, it will contain the state of the Enum that you set,

For example:

```
System.out.println(Paula);
```

Would return:

```
FEMALE
```